# FFMPEG filtergraph 'warning, too many B-frames in a row'

Tags: c, video, filter, ffmpeg, racket

I am trying to append two videos together with FFmpeg's filtergraph. One video is sized 1920x1080 at 30fps, and another 1280x720 at 25fps. Both use yuv420p, and have the same pixel densities. I am currently ignoring the audio tracks. The following is my filtergraph:

```
[video2]fifo[video3];
[video3]pad=width=1920:height=1080[video9];
[video9]fps=fps=25[video11];
[video11]setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS[video17];

[video6]fifo[video7];
[video7]pad=width=1920:height=1080[video13];
[video13]fps=fps=25[video15];
[video15]setpts=expr=PTS-STARTPTS[video19];

[video17][video19]concat=v=1:a=0:n=2[video21];
[video21]pad=width=1920:height=1080[video23];
[video23]fps=fps=25[video25];
[video25]format=pix_fmts=yuv420p[video27]
```

The first chain tries to convert the first video into a common format, that starts at 0 for the concat filter. The second chain does the same as the first. Finally, the third chain concatenates them videos together, and sets some properties for the resulting playlist.

Unfortunately, when I run this error, ffmpeg repeatedly outputs:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x7fc16a810600] warning, too many B-frames in a row
```

When finished, I see the first video, padded to the correct resolution and frame rate, but instead of the second Video I see black. Additionally, the entire video is several days in length, starting with the first Video and ending in several days of just black.

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error, as it seems like I am setting the videos to have identical properties. What am I missing?

Also, for what its worth, I am using FFmpeg's C API rather than the command line tool. I am using libavformat/libavcodec/libavutil to do the encoding/decoding and libavfilter for the filtergraph.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: What point does it violate?

Comment: I mean, it seems like a specific programming related question.

Comment: Encoding a video using ffmpeg has exactly what to do with writing software?

Comment: (FFmpeg CLI Qs go on SuperUser.) That error looks like a decoder error. When you crosspost there, include the full log.

Comment: *when you delete this question and post it over on [su]...

Comment: I mean, that is the full log. The output just repeats that line over and over again. FWIW, I also am using FFmpeg's C API.

Comment: Full log includes ffmpeg banner, input details, and the rest of the output messages.

Comment: Sorry, what banner? The command I ran was: `$ racket ffgraph.rkt` And the output was just: `[mpeg4 @ 0x7fc16a810600] warning, too many B-frames in a row` a couple thousand times? (I apologize if that's a dumb question, I honestly am not sure what banner you are talking about.)

Comment: Is racket executing a ffmpeg cli command? Then stderr output of ffmpeg is needed.

Comment: Nope, I'm using the C API, via these FFI bindings: https://github.com/videolang/video/blob/master/video/private/ffmpeg.rkt

Comment: Although, if as you say, its a decoding error, then the filtergraph is not what I need to put here, so I will see if I can make a minimal decoding example that exhibits the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Also yup. If I drop the playlist and just decode the second video I get that error. Good catch @Mulvya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mulvya pointed out in the comments, this error actually had nothing to do with the filtergraph, but instead is related to the encoder/decoder. One of the two files in the playlist caused this error, and setting the [`max_b_frames`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structAVCodecContext.html#a3e5334a611a3e2a6a653805bb9e2d4d4) of the `AVCodecContext` struct did the trick.

Since I am using Racket, the line I needed was something like:

```
(set-avcodec-context-max-b-frames! ctx 8)
```